# flutter : firebase_auth sample works only android, and error (exception) appears on iOS

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example/lib

A month ago, when I created a new flutter project, registered it in firebase, and ran the sample on the above page as it was, I was able to register and sign in with both the iOS simulator and android emulator.

When I run the app again today, an exception occurs on iOS, and even if I enter the email/password on the user registration screen and press the submit button, the screen display does not change at all. The situation is that user registration has not been completed.

With the android emulator, user registration and sign-in can be completed without problems. Of course, I have set the "email/password" method to "enabled" in the firebase console.
The exception message is shown below.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode... Running Xcode build... Xcode build done.                              
31.0s Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64975/Xcy6RyGWDS0=/ws Syncing files to device iPhone SE (2nd generation)... ), error=(null) on <SOConfigurationClient: 0x600000bfa800> } [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED, The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section., null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18) <asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
#3      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:356:48)
#4      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:64:23)
#5      FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:64:10)
#6      RegisterPageState._register (package:myapp101/register_page.dart:89:44)
#7 <…>
```

What could be the cause?

2020/6/29,15:30

When I tried with "sign-in with google", it shifts to the login screen with the google account, but when I actually perform the authentication process, the following exception message is displayed and I can not log in again.

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED, The identity provider configuration is disabled., null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18) <asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
#3      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:356:48)
#4      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:161:23)
#5      FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:208:10)
#6      _GoogleSignInSectionState._signInWithGoogle (package:myapp101/signin_page.dart:423:22)
#7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
#8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085<…>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages says:

> The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.

So you'll want to go to the [Authentication page](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/providers) in the Firebase console, and enable the provider your code uses.

Comment: I have set the "email/password" method to "enabled" in the firebase console.

Comment: The error message mentions `_GoogleSignInSectionState`, so it seems *that* is the provider you're trying to use (and hence should enable in the console).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Excuse me, for some reason I downloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist file again and used it, and the error no longer occurs on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, for some reason I downloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist file again and used it, and the error no longer occurs on iOS.